# Git Checkout - missing commit

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with GitHub. I made a lot of changes to one file in Xcode, but I wanted to see what was there yesterday, So I commited changes and in terminal, i wrote

`- git checkout d4d037929154c55376af7952ce40e014465f4c77 -b TestBranch` (commit from yesterday), now I want to switch back to the original file,

but when I  write `git log --graph --all --decorate --branches=master`  there is only the commit from yesterday?

I'm pretty new to GitHub, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume that you have two branches `master` and `TestBranch`. I think that `git checkout master` should do the work but if not could you write results of `git status` and `git log` on branch master and on branch TestBranch?

Comment: [Git](https://git-scm.com) and [Github](https://github.com) are two different entities. Git is a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), Github hosts Git repositories and provides a web interface to access and manage them. Apparently Github is not involved in your quest(ion).